# Mixing two CAF file together

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I have a problem here, in mixing of two CAF file.

**First CAF File ->** Fetching via a given url from server side

**Second CAF File ->** Recording with AVAudioRecorder

**Fetch File Size -** 10 sec

**Recording File Size -** 7 sec

How to mix these two given audio files in a single file, Please give me some sample code for same. Also format must be in CAF only.

Comment: With 'mix' do you mean make 1 file that plays both sounds at the same time or concat them into 1 file of 17 seconds playing the first file and then the second? For the latter I have a way to do this with .wav files. Maybe you can use this code for your problem.

Comment: @dragon112 "Mix" means both file play together in a single file after mixing both together. For example, if one of them is a theme audio file and you record our something own and then mix the record file with the theme file.

Comment: @sandy What have you tried already? What problems did you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AVMutableComposition in the AVFoundation framework can do this; you do something like

```
AVMutableComposition *comp = [AVMutableComposition new];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compTrack1 = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
    preferredTrackId:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compTrack2 = [comp addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
    preferredTrackId:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVAssetTrack *srcTrack1 = UseAVAssetToGetTrackfromFirstFile();
AVAssetTrack *srcTrack2 = UseAVAssetToGetTrackfromSecondFile();

NSError *error = nil;

    [compTrack1 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, kCMTimePositiveInfinity)
                            ofTrack:srcTrack1  
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

    CheckForError(error);

    [compTrack2 insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, kCMTimePositiveInfinity)
                            ofTrack:srcTrack2  
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

    CheckForError(error);

// emit mix from the composition here with a reader or whatever.
```

You cans set relative levels with the composition too. If you needed to do anything more fancy than just levels and pan, though, you'd have to create an AudioUnit graph.

Comment: How would you set the pan in this situation?

Comment: I don't believe you can control pan in an AVComposition, you have to us an AVAudioMix

Comment: Yes indeed. I went to this solution. Then you have to set a MTAudioProcessingTap with an AudioUnit (say a multichannelMixer) in your AVAudioMix. During the callback of the MTAudioProcessingTap you can set the pan of the audio unit.